# Laravel - How to set faker locale in phpunit tests?

Tags: laravel, phpunit, faker

I'm able to change `faker` locale in my application in `config/app.php` to `pt_BR` changing `'faker_locale' => 'pt_BR',` and it works fine in my factories but not in my test cases. This is how im importing faker in my Tests:

```
namespace Tests\Unit;

use Tests\TestCase;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithFaker;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;
use App\Models\Proprietario;

class ProprietarioTest extends TestCase
{
    use WithFaker, RefreshDatabase;


    public function testStore(){


        $attributes = [
            'name' => $this->faker->name,
            'email' => $this->faker->email,
            'address' => $this->faker->city,
            'phone' => $this->faker->cellPhoneNumber,
            'municipio' => $this->faker->randomDigit,
        ];
        $response = $this->post('/api/v1/proprietario', $attributes);

        $response->assertStatus(201);
        $createdArea = Proprietario::latest();
        $this->assertDatabaseHas('proprietarios', $attributes);
    }
```

The test will fail in `$this->faker->cellPhoneNumber` because it's not available in default locale. I'm using Laravel 5.8 and PHP 7.2

Comment: You should check and see what the `WithFaker` Trait is giving you out of the box. You may need to modify the faker instance in your own `setUp()` method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The WithFaker trait gives you a method you can use

```php
$this->faker('nl_NL')->postcode // dutch postcode
```

If you want to use it for all tests, overide the setupFaker in your test(s)

```
protected function setUpFaker()
{
    $this->faker = $this->makeFaker('nl_NL');
}
```